# how to save the current date and time in to a text file vb

Tags: vb.net

I'm a beginner in VB and I can't seem to find a solution to that. This program has a puzzle game and upon finishing the game, the program prompts the player if he/she wants to play again. If yes, play again, else Me.Close() then the fastest time to finish the puzzle is going to be saved in a text file along with the player name and the date and time.

This is what I have as of now:

```
Private Sub FrmLv1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Dim FileNum As Integer
    Dim timeNow As DateTime
    If MessageBox.Show("Do you want to quit?", "Quit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then
        e.Cancel = True
            If Convert.ToDouble(CInt(Label1.Text)) < HighScore Then
                playerName = EnterName.MltLnTxtBxWrMrk.Text
                HighScore = Convert.ToDouble(CInt(Label1.Text))
                timeNow = DateTime.Now.ToString
                HighScoreFrm.bestPlayer.Text = "Best Player: " & playerName
                HighScoreFrm.fastestTime.Text = "Fastest Time: " & HighScore
                HighScoreFrm.dateFinished.Text = "Date Finished: " & timeNow
                FileNum = FreeFile()
                FileOpen(FileNum, "score.txt", OpenMode.Output)
                PrintLine(FileNum, playerName)
                PrintLine(FileNum, HighScore)
                PrintLine(FileNum, timeNow)
                FileClose(FileNum)
            End If
    Else
        Pick_a_game.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub

 Private Sub HighScore_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles HS.Click
    Dim FileNum As Integer
    FileNum = FreeFile()
    FileOpen(FileNum, "score.txt", OpenMode.Input)
    Do Until EOF(FileNum)
        playerName = LineInput(FileNum)
        HighScore = LineInput(FileNum)
        timeNow = LineInput(FileNum)
    Loop
    HighScoreFrm.bestPlayer.Text = "Best Player: " & playerName
    HighScoreFrm.fastestTime.Text = "Fastest Time: " & HighScore
    HighScoreFrm.dateFinished.Text = "Date Finished: " & timeNow
    HighScoreFrm.Show()
    FileClose(FileNum)
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim elapsed As TimeSpan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(time)
    Label1.Text = elapsed.Minutes.ToString & elapsed.Seconds.ToString
End Sub
```

Also, I'm getting this error: System.IO.EndOfStreamException was unhandled {"Input past end of file."}

Help me please! Thanks

Comment: I advise against using the legacy `FreeFile`, `FileOpen`, and `FileClose` functions - they are intended for supporting VB programs that predate even VB6 (VB6 had `FileSystemObject` for working with files). You should use `System.IO` instead.

Comment: [**How to: Write Text to a File**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w(v=vs.110).aspx) _**(ignore the very last example as that does not apply to WinForms!)**_